# Making rotate in dropdown menu with CSS

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

Hi ı made a dropdown menu but ı want to when ı click it the angle should rotate 180 deg

[When it seems in close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I954T.png)

[when it seems in open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q59K0.png)

I tried to use .touch checked but it didn't work. How can ı make the rotation and when ı click it again (when ı close the dropdown) the angle should rotate 180 deg again ı don't want to use javascript firstly so that if can you help me about this with css ı will be very happy. But if we have to use javascript no problem you can help with javascript too.

```
        <label for="touch" class="nav-label"><span id="services">Hizmetlerimiz</span>
          <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down angle" style="color: #f282a6;"></i>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="touch" class="touch">
        <ul class="slide">
          <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

````
.slide {
  list-style-type: none;
  clear:both;
  width:100%;
  height:0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .4s ease;
}
    .touch:checked ~ .angle{
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: transform 200ms linear;
}
.slide li {padding : 30px;}

#touch {position: absolute; opacity: 0; height: 0px;}    

#touch:checked + .slide {height: 300px;}  ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the checkbox to be before the `<label>`. This is so that the general sibling operator (`~`) can work for us. Furthermore, the `.angle` element is *not* a sibling of the checkbox, but rather a *child* of a sibling. So we will need to use a descendent combination to select it properly.

```css
.slide {
  list-style-type: none;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .4s ease;
}

.touch:checked ~ * .angle {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: transform 200ms linear;
}

.slide li {
  padding: 30px;
}

#touch {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
}

#touch:checked ~ .slide {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<input type="checkbox" id="touch" class="touch">
<label for="touch" class="nav-label">
  <span id="services">Hizmetlerimiz</span>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down angle" style="color: #f282a6;"></i>
</label>
<ul class="slide">
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
</ul>
```